# How to fix "unresolved reference: int" in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I've just started  learning the basics of the Kotlin  to create Android apps. I don't understand why I cannot run my program even though I'm following a tutorial.

Here's my code:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var x: int = 3
    println("value of x is $x")
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get this error:

```
Unresolved reference: int
```

[image: unresolved reference]

Comment: You seem to be new to this, your intellij will automatically suggest you that you have misspelled `Int` as `int`, try using the IDE to it's max potential!

Comment: you are totally right how did I miss it!  thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use `Int` instead of `int`

All of the [basic types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html) in Kotlin start with a capital letter. This is different from Java, which has [primitive types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) that start with a lowercase letter. You should replace `int` with `Int`.